# Laravel: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, text, types

I have a table with a column 'hotel'. The project is created in Laravel 5.4, so I used Migrations.

```
$table->string('hotel', 50);
```

This is MYSQL VARCHAR (50). It was working good, because when I was developing I used short hotel names like *"HILTON NEW YORK 5*"*.

Now the project is on production and customer asked why they can't input long hotel names. I've tested it with such a mock hotel name as *"Long long long long long long long long long and very-very-very long hotel name 5 stars"*

It gave me an error:

> "SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for
> column 'hotel' at row 1"

I've opened database in my Sequel Pro and changed it

- first to VARCHAR (255)
- then to TEXT

After each change I tested it with the same "Long long long long long long long long long and very-very-very long hotel name 5 starts" and get the same error (see above).

I've checked the type of column with

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM table_name
```

and it gave me

> Field | Type
>
> hotel | text

so the type of the field is 'text' indeed  (65 535 characters).

Maybe it's somehow connected with Laravel Migration file (see above) where I set VARCHAR (50) in the beginning? But I can't re-run migration on production, because the table has data now.

Would appreciate any help.

---

**UPDATE:**
I discovered that it actually saves that long hotel name in the DB. But user still gets this annoying mistake every time after submitting the form...

Comment: You most certainly can create a migration to change the field type. As long as it's something similar it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As always, try it on your local copy *just in case*, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi, guys. Thank you. I've created a new migration as Alexey explained in his answer below and ran it (on local), but the erro is still shows up every time form is submitted....:(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to create a new migration, register it with `composer du` command and run `php artisan migrate` command to change type of the column:

```
Schema::table('the_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('hotel', 255)->change();
});
```

Comment: Hi, Alexey. How can I run a migration on the server without loosing all the  inputed data.

Comment: That's what migrations for. If you'll add a new migration just to change column type and run `php artisan migrate` command, no data will be lost. But looks like you're new to this, so I'd really recommend you to practice on the local machine first and backup the data.

Comment: 1) should i write something to "    public function down(){ } in migration file?
 
2) tried to run a migration and got a mistake "Changing columns for table "tours" requires Doctrine DBAL; install "doctrine/dbal".  

gonna install it and run on the local server.

Comment: Yes, you need to install the package. Also, you should modify the column in `up()` method and in `down()` you need to modify it back it the state it's now. The `down()` method is executed when you run the `php artisan migrate:rollback` command.

Comment: "in down() you need to modify it back it the stat it's now" - didn't get it... Does your answer suggest to CREATE a NEW migration file or update the one I had in my project before for this table? (if new, I don't see anything in down() ....

Comment: Since you have live DB with real data, you should create a new migration for this.

Comment: I've just tested it in local. The column type changed to VARCHAR (255), but I still get the same mistake when submitting a long hotel name (93 characters in the last test)

Comment: Hope you come back to this topic:)

Comment: @SergejFomin sounds like it's related to MySQL engine settings, I don't think I'll be able to help with that.

Comment: Your answer did work, thank you. It was another table named 'previous_tours' where 'hotel' field also was to be re-arranged in the same manner.

Answer (score 25):

On your local development, try changing the column type to:

```
$table->longText('columnName')
```

from your migration file. That solved it for me. But if you have gone live, then create a new migration just as Alexey has suggested and then use `longText()` column type.

Comment: $table->text('columnName') should be enough for most of the cases

Comment: The longText() holds much data than text(). So, he knows he's going to be dealing a very large size of text, longText() will do the job.

Comment: [Long text will hold up to 4GB of text](https://electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/). A hotel name is definitely never going to be that long. text() will be fine here. And if it didn't, you'd want to bump to mediumText() before going to longText().

Answer (score 7):

I was storing pictures as base64 on a text colum so I got a SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'picture' at row 1
```

I did my migration as

```
$table->text('picture')
```

then I changed de column picture as:

```
$table->mediumText('picture')
```

I realiced that text column allows to store only 64 KB

TEXT: 65,535 characters - 64 KB
MEDIUMTEXT: 16,777,215 - 16 MB
LONGTEXT: 4,294,967,295 characters - 4 GB

For more info visit: [understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/)

Comment: `$table->text('picture') ` solved my issue

Answer (score 4):

Change column's datatype from string to text and do not give length.

Answer (score 2):

change the type of column from`string` to `text`.

Then run a migrate refresh using `php artisan migrate:refesh`

Comment: Why would that type change help? OP mentioned "I've opened database in my Sequel Pro and changed it

first to VARCHAR (255)
then to TEXT
After each change I tested it with the same "Long long long long long long long long long and very-very-very long hotel name 5 starts" and get the same error (see above)."

Comment: data lost after migrate:refresh !!

Answer (score 2):

Change column's datatype from string to text and do not give length.

```
$table->text('hotel')->change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution of this error
`"SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'hotel' at row 1"`
open Mysql and click on change button in the furent of that column and make length/values = 111

Answer (score 1):

Change data type of the column in the database to **'longtext'** if **'text'** data type not working

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('content')->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('content', 65536)->change();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was connected to the update of MariaDB.

What helped:

In Mariadb config file (linux machine) `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`
in the section `[mariadb]` I added this line:

```
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Restart MariaDB and the exception is gone.

Answer (score 0):

$table->text('body'); <===== change the **string** to **text**

1. string can only support 256 character
2. text support more

Answer (score 0):

When I received this error, it was because existing data in the table did not conform to the new length. So I just increased the length and it worked.

I was trying:

```
 $table->string('name', 10)->unique()->change();
```

To change the column from TinyText and make it unique. But one column had 12 characters. So I made it this:

```
$table->string('name', 20)->unique()->change();
```