# Not able to add 400 characters in mysql database

Tags: mysql, laravel

i am trying to store 400 characters long key in mysql database using laravel.
i have tried string, text, longtext in laravel migration table but not worked

i am getting this error

```
code
:
"22001"
message
:
"SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'api_token' at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `api_token` = eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9lbnRyYW5jZWluZGlhLm5ldFwvYXBpXC9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjMyMjE4MTcsImV4cCI6NDY3NjgyMTgxNywibmJmIjoxNTIzMjIxODE3LCJqdGkiOiIzclFvNGpzMmg0aUZQcmRvIiwic3ViIjozMiwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.LxjArPNzTGqZh59JE4YN87oQUajfM28vyl2pnTokweA, `updated_at` = 2018-04-08 21:10:19 where `id` = 32)"
status_code
:
500
```

Comment: Show users table definition.

Comment: Also you forgot the single quotes for the field api_token value.

Comment: Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('mobile')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('api_token',400)->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

Answer (score 0):

It may be this problem:

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

I had similar problem and changing like its on this post made errors go away.

Or try changing table field like this:

```
Schema::table('the_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('hotel', 255)->change();
});
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48477882/8517929)